# RethinkDB composite primary key Join

Tags: rethinkdb

I was wondering how would you do a join on a table with a composite primary key.

The composite key is achieved by using an array in the primary key field

Table 1

```
{id: key1, other: data}
```

Table 2

```
{id: [key1, key2], other: data}
```

So what I want is to join on table2.id[0] with table1

```
r.table("table1").eq_join("id[0]", r.table("table2")).run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `eqJoin` here because it requires keys to be strictly equal (strings are not arrays and vice versa).
This also means the best performance among all join operations, so this is why `eqJoin` is designed to accept a field name only, not an expression.
You seem to want [`innerJoin`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/inner_join/) that can handle you case but sacrificing some performance (actually I'm not sure about real performance implications):

```js
r.table('table1')
    .innerJoin(
        r.table('table2'),
        (doc1, doc2) => doc1('id').eq(doc2('id').nth(0))
    )
```

Note that you can use expressions you were trying to use in your question (`"id[0]"` merely means a field name for `eqJoin`).

Comment: say i wanted i wanted result =  table1 { "id": key1, "table2": table2 } so the right result inside the left how would that be done

Comment: @Mohamed20884 This is out of the scope of this question and requires more work. Please post a new question.